# How can I query a List for different ContentTypes?

Tags: 2013, content-type, csom

I am developing a console application to extract data from a SharePoint 2013 server using the [.NET client object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Dn423226.aspx#bk_QueryNETcsom) of the [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585):

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(SharePointUrl))
{
    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

    var camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();

    var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems, GetFields(fields));

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    return listItems.ToList();
}
```

This is the GetFields() method I call to construct the list of fields I request:

```
private Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>[] GetFields(IEnumerable<string> fields)
{
    return fields
        .Select(field => (Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>)(items => items.Include(item => item[field])))
        .ToArray();
}
```

While looping through the results, I retrieve the value of a User-type field like this:

```
var employee = (FieldUserValue)listItem[fieldName];
```

There is one big list -- `"Demands"` -- that is giving me troubles for some User-type fields: whenever I even include these as a field that needs to be retrieved via the `GetFields()` method (see above), I get the infamous "Value does not fall within the expected range." error. For instance, `"DTBusinessResponsible"` can be retrieved, yet `"DTSupplyLeadResponsible"` cannot.

I have been told that `"Demands"` contains two `ContentTypes`: `"Demand"` and `"I-Demand"`. The fields that are giving me issues are exclusive to `"I-Demand"`.

I cannot figure out how I can retrieve these missing fields. <s>I suppose I need to change the content type when I query the `"Demands"` list, but I'm not clear on how to do this.</s>

---

**UPDATE:** I've tried retrieving the `ContentType`s for `"Demand"` and `"I-Demand"` and adding them to `list`:

```
var demandContentType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(contentTypeByName["Demand"]);
var iDemandContentType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(contentTypeByName["I-Demand"]);

list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
list.ContentTypes.AddExistingContentType(demandContentType);
list.ContentTypes.AddExistingContentType(iDemandContentType);
```

No use, I get an error telling me both `ContentType`s are already present.

---

**UPDATE:** I've [also asked this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32521227/648075).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through much trial and error, I have managed to get this to work:

```
var fields = new List<string>
{
    "DTSupplyAccountable",
    "DTSupplyLeadResponsible",
    "Author",
    "Editor",
    "ID"
};

var viewXml = new StringBuilder();

viewXml.AppendLine("<ViewFields>");
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    viewXml.AppendFormat("<FieldRef Name=\"{0}\" />", field).AppendLine();
}
viewXml.AppendLine("</ViewFields>");

viewXml.AppendLine("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ContentType\" /><Value Type=\"Computed\">I-Demand</Value></Eq></Where></Query>");

var camlQuery = new CamlQuery {ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">{0}</View>", viewXml)};

List<ListItem> results;

using (var clientContext = GetClientContext())
{
    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Demands");
    var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    results = listItems.ToList();
}
```

Here is the crucial detail (apart from the obvious `<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ContentType\" /><Value Type=\"Computed\">I-Demand</Value></Eq></Where>`):

```
ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">{0}</View>", viewXml)
```

In fact, it's `Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"` that is the important part. I encountered it when looking with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to the various requests that were sent to the server and noticing that the working calls all included this:

```xml
<Property Name="ViewXml" Type="String">&lt;View Scope="RecursiveAll"&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;Query&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;/Query&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/View&gt;</Property>
```

On a whim I decided to add `Scope="RecursiveAll"` to my code, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you check for each item field ContentTypeID to get current content type and retrieve contextual field.

To get content type ID with name, you can call function like this

```
var listContentType = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle).ContentTypes.GetByName(listContentTypeName) and retrieve ID
```

Comment: The problem is *I cannot even retrieve these fields*. When I add them via `clientContext.Load(listItems, GetFields(fields));` ***the query crashes***. Both "Deamnds" and "I-Demand" are part of the `ContentTypes` of `list`.