# User-type fields in CamlQuery ViewFields return null

Tags: 2013, caml-query, camlviewfields

I am trying to return several User-type fields from SharePoint 2013 like this:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(myUrl))
{
    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

    var listItems = list.GetItems(GetCamlQuery(fields));

    clientContext.Load(listItems);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    return listItems.ToList();
}

private CamlQuery GetCamlQuery(IEnumerable<string> fields)
{
    var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

    var viewXml = new StringBuilder();

    viewXml.AppendLine("<ViewFields>");
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        viewXml.AppendFormat("<FieldRef Name='{0}' />", field).AppendLine();
    }
    viewXml.AppendLine("</ViewFields>");

    camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View>{0}</View>", viewXml);

    return camlQuery;
}
```

However, all of these User-fields return null, even though I'm sure some of them should contain values. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

- I am using the proper names: the query doesn't fail, and the `FieldValues` collection contains results for these fields, except they're all `null`.
- When I use the `Display Name`, that field isn't in the result set.
- I've added other fields, and they also return null, except for `"ID"` and `"Title"`.

(I also just noticed I am only receiving 10 items as a result, but there are many more entries in the List I am querying. So that's another thing that is wrong...)

Comment: Can you try setting `camlQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = true;`, just a random guess :)

Comment: Everything seems to be fine with your code. My bet is on the part not visible in your code - `fields` collection. Make sure that you use valid internal names for all fields.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri There is [no `ViewFieldsOnly` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery_properties.aspx).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a workaround:

```
var loadedListItems = new List<ListItem>();

using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(myUrl))
{
    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(configuration.ListName);

    var camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
    var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var loadedListItem in listItems.ToList().Select(x => list.GetItemById(x.Id)))
    {
        clientContext.Load(loadedListItem);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        loadedListItems.Add(loadedListItem);
    }
}
```

Note how the code iterates through the result of `list.GetItems(camlQuery);` and then executes `list.GetItemById(x.Id)` for each result. This does indeed work and returns items with `"Author"` and `"Editor"` filled in.

**Important note:** I do realize **the performance impact** (right now this takes 40-50 seconds), but this is the ***only*** solution that has solved my problem. I'd much rather have someone solve the issue that is causing the impossibility to retrieve those values via the regular query, but apparently that isn't happening.

Comment: Oh my. I understand that it might have helped with your problem and maybe performance isn't an issue in your on premise environment. But this is simply terrible. Your code will issue a CSOM request for each item on the list. If there are 1000 items on the list, it will issue 1000 web service calls and the 1000 SQL queries (best case scenario). If you execute this code in context of remote hosted app, SharePoint (both on prem and online) will deny service with `429 Too many request` result. Not to mention executing this against O365 may take few minutes. It surely isn't a valid solution.

Comment: And before someone suggests that. In general case it is possible to batch multiple operations in one execute. So it seems like you could move `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` outside of `foreach`. This will make one CSOM call to load all the items. Unfortunately scheduling 1000 operations for one request can also be denied by SharePoint (assuming that it won't exceed WCF's message size limits first).

Answer (score 0):

You probably know this, but to be safe, each SharePoint field has three names, which can all be different: Internal Name, Static Name, and Display Name.

I have not used this particular interface. In the server side interfaces, sometimes Display Name is needed, and sometimes Internal Name is needed, and sometimes it will try more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give an empty query and specify the column selection using the lambda expression in the load statement. Check out [How to: Retrieve List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Please add some description from the link.

Comment: Did that, doesn't work. This is one specific list where this is happening, a dozen other lists return values without a problem. See also http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/156904/45188 .

Answer (score -1):

**After This Code**

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View>{0}</View>", viewXml);
```

**Add This line**

```
camlQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

Comment: This is CSOM code. Property 'ViewFieldsOnly' is not available on [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery_members.aspx) class.